# Change gridViewItem's background color after first and second click on it

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

My point is to change gridViewItem's background color to Blue after first click and to Red after second click on it, then Blue, then Red ...

Here is my c# code but it threw an exception 'System.NullReferenceException' on "gvi.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Blue);":

```
   private void GridViewItem_Click (Object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e!=null)
        {

            for (int numberOfClick= 1; numberOfClick <100; ++numberOfClick)
            {
                GridViewItem gvi = (GridViewItem)NameOf_ItemClick.ContainerFromItem(e);

                if (numberOfClick % 2 == 0)
                {

                    gvi.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);

                }
                else
                {
                    gvi.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Blue);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Here is my `Xaml` code:

```
<Page
x:Class="HNT_listView2.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:HNT_listView2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:data="using:HNT_listView2.Models"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background= "Salmon" Margin="0,0,10,0"  >

    <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyContactList}" 
              ItemClick="GridViewItem_Click" Name="NameOf_ItemClick"
              IsItemClickEnabled="True" >


        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Contact">
                <StackPanel >
                    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyout Placement="Top">
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Call"/>
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Send a message"/>
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete"/>
                        </MenuFlyout>
                    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>

                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">


                    <Image Width="100" Height="120" Source="{x:Bind Photo}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock FontSize="30" Text="{x:Bind Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="30" Text="{x:Bind Phone}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>

    </GridView>


</Grid>
```

My Contact.cs in Models:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}


public class ContactManager
{
    public static List<Contact> GetContacts()
    {
        var contact1 = new List<Contact>();
        contact1.Add(new Contact { Name = "Nguyen Van A", Phone = "0168111222", Photo = "Assets/1.jpg" });
        contact1.Add(new Contact { Name = "Tran Van B", Phone = " 0168333444", Photo = "Assets/2.jpg" });
        contact1.Add(new Contact { Name = "Le Van C", Phone = "0166555666", Photo = "Assets/3.jpg" });

        return contact1;
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you !

Comment: Where does it throw the exception? Specify the line.

Comment: It threw exception on " gvi.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Blue);"

Comment: Binding? Did you bind anything to it?

Comment: I've editted . Please check

Comment: You're passing the ItemClickEventArgs object `e` instead of the clicked item `e.ClickedItem` to `ContainerFromItem`.

Comment: Oh thank you @DecadeMoon , code can run fine now , but it is changed only to Blue after first click, cannot be changed to Red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a boolean as the counter?

```
   private byte GridViewSwitch = 0;
   private void GridViewItem_Click (Object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e!=null)
        {
            var item = (GridViewItem)NameOf_ItemClick.ContainerFromItem(e);
            switch(GridViewSwitch)
            case 0 : item.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red); GridViewSwitch++;  break ;
           case 1 : item.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Blue); GridViewSwitch++;   break ;

            case 2: item.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Green); GridViewSwitch=0;   break ;

        }
    }
```

If you think this answer is correct and helpful, click the tick mark on the left to approve it!

Comment: I tried your code, no error left, I could click on the items but no color-change

Comment: But if I change back to

                GridViewItem gvi = (GridViewItem)NameOf_ItemClick.ContainerFromItem(e.ClickedItem);

                if (gvi.Background == new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Blue))
                { gvi.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red); }

                else { gvi.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Blue); }


It could change to Blue after first click  and could not change to Red

Comment: It changed to Blue after first click but not changed to Red after second one (still Blue). 
By the way, thank you for your patience .

Comment: Revamped the entire answer. Not going to bother with getting the color for now.

Comment: Great, it works, Thank you so much @Happypig375.
Now I want to change it to Red, then to Blue , then to Green ...

Comment: Oh, I'll try on my own :( 
(but no hope , I know)

Comment: Wait wait wait I can do it

Comment: It's really kind of you ^^